# Fibonacci-like formula for Padovan sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

For the Fibonacci sequence, one can show the following and easy to calculate equation :
$$\forall n\in \mathbb Z,~\mathcal F_n=\mathcal F_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1}^2-(-1)^n\mathcal F_{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}^2$$
Is there any analog for the Padovan sequence ? (computing in logarithmic time with only two or three recursive calls)

In fact, I'm looking for a generalisation for superior orders (Padovan sequence is some 3-Fibonacci sequence).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I ask, are you just interested in a rapid calculation of the Padovan sequence, or is it something more sophisticated? If it's the former, there is a Binet-type formula and even a simplification of that if it's just the Padovan sequence that's of interest (i.e., not including the Perrin and other offshoots). To wit, $P(n)=\text{Round}(ap^n)$, where $p=1.324717957244746$ and $a= 0.722124418303113$.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now I have heard about these numbers, but there are matrix forms for the Padovan (and Perrin) numbers, see e.g. http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/941673/ and others.

If you have such a formula, you can use a **fast matrix powering algorithm** like [Square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). (You could do the same for Fibonacci numbers.)

This is described in https://oeis.org/A000931:

`a(n) is the top left entry of the n-th power of the 3 X 3 matrix 
[0, 0, 1; 1, 0, 1; 0, 1, 0] or of the 3 X 3 matrix [0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1; 1, 1, 0].`

Comment: Yes thank you. In fact, it is better to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem one this matrix.